# MVC / websockets in node.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, node.js, websocket, pylons

I'm thinking about building some intranet applications that make use of websockets. I'm currently using Python/Pylons for my web framework on the server, and doing polling to update items in the DOM of the page. Pylons is not well suited to communicate with websockets (IMHO) as it uses a thread per connection. I'm considering using node.js as the server to communicate with the websocket connections from my web application. Here's the "10,000 foot view" of my application:

- Pylons delivers the web content (html, css, images, javascript, etc.)
- JavasSript on the page application opens up websocket(s) to the node.js server
- The node.js server pushes data to the application through the websocket
- JavaScript updates the page DOM elements based on the data from the websocket

The data in the case above comes from a MySQL database, which is where my question comes from. I've set up MVC type applications before, and can do the same kind of thing in node.js. However, if I have a long lived websocket open to the node.js server, how does node.js become aware of changes in the Model and push them out to the application? For instance if I want to update totals presented on the web application page, and those totals change due to actions in the system outside of node.js (other web applications), how is node.js notified of those changes? The thing that comes to mind is to have node.js poll the database for various changes and propagate the changes to the various Views. But to me that just sounds like I'm moving my polling from the web application to the node.js server?

Anyone have any ideas, suggestions or pointers on this?

Thanks in advance!
Doug

Comment: why can't the pylons app notify node.js?

Comment: It could, which is kind of what I'm doing now. The JavaScript polls the Pylons application using AJAX/JSON to get data. However, this method is often polling for data that hasn't changed. Plus, all the "instances" of my app running on different users browsers are polling for data.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

- Let the Python scripts notify the node.js application (via a socket or via HTTP)
- Or poll from node.js because it is not aware of changes outside it's environment

Polling is considered bad because it doesn't scale. When having a single process that polls does scale because it doesn't need more connections when another user connects. So basically:

```
// query every second or so
setInterval(function () {
    // query database
    doSomeDatabaseStuff(function (res) {
        // check dirty
        if (res.changed) {
             // notify all clients
             allConnectedSockets.forEach(function (socket) {
                 socket.send({ msg: "update" });
             });
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

This way you have one single process polling the database, and a scalable architecture to notify your connected clients. The database can still be filled from any source.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was kind of thinking about this after posting my original question; having node.js do the polling means that only it is doing the polling no matter how many clients (web apps) are attached to it. I guess one of the things I was looking for was how different domains of the application/database could set the "dirty" bit and somehow make node.js aware of that change. I suppose that could be a change notification from a "controller" that is sent to node.js which causes it to update its observers, which might eliminate the polling.

Comment: The dirty setting can be done in various ways. You can either write data to a database, and if the MAX(id) is higher than the last time, then something probably changed. Or you can open a connection from Python to node.js, this can be done via another socket, or via plain HTTP, and let Python notify the application via that way. The node.js app can respond to this by notifying it's clients.

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js is an MVC framework for node that has the unique distinction of RESTfully routing Socket.io messages in the same way as your Express routes.

Sails currently uses Sequelize, and is configured by default to use mySQL (but also supports SQLite and Postgres).  We're switching to a model that lets you choose your own ORM, which will allow us to support JugglingDB (which adds support for Mongo, amongst others)

It also comes bundled with a front-end component, Mast. Mast provides similar functionality to Meteor, in that it allows you to talk directly to the database from the client. If you need to provide more complex functionality, you just add a controller on the backend.

More here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will check out Sails.js and see if it works for me. Again, thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Let me know if you have feedback.  I'm trying to pull out the parts of it that are functionally independent into smaller modules so people can use what works for them (i.e. we just took the asset compiler out and made a separate node module.)